# CSS, imposing lines and shapes onto a button?

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to make a Gomoku game. The board looks like a regular grid, except pieces are placed on intersections instead of spaces.

[image: looks like this]

So far, I have a grid like this [tic-tac-toe example](https://codepen.io/ericnakagawa/pen/vXpjwZ?editors=0010) from the Reactjs tutorial.

The relevant CSS from it is:

```
.board-row:after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.square {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  float: left;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  margin-right: -1px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 34px;
}

.square:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

They make a grid of buttons where each space is a button. However I need to make my intersections clickable, not the spaces. I am planning to make buttons like [image: my buttons] this, in order to make the board. The blue borders will be invisible and I drew them to see each button clearly. The black circle in the last one is a piece played on the intersection.

How can I add these lines and circles to my buttons? Or is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

well if you have a div you can do this

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

div:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 45px;
  right: 45px;
}


div:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  top:45px;
  bottom: 45px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

working example http://jsbin.com/mupucurebi/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 1):

Use as container a `flexbox` with `padding` and `flex-wrap: wrap`. Now all you have to do is render 64 elements that have the right size.

In addition, you can use a gradient pattern as the background. The background was based on the pattern in [enjoycss](http://enjoycss.com/gallery/gradient_patterns/hj#background).

```js
const { render } = ReactDOM;

const Board = () => (
  <div className="bg">
  {
    Array.from({ length: 64 }, (i, k) => (
      <div key={ k } className="piece" />
    ))
  }
  </div>
);

render(
  <Board />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 2px;
}

.bg {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 272px;
  height: 269px;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  border: none;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  text-overflow: clip;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #000000 0, #FFFFFF 2px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 2px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%), linear-gradient(90deg, #000000 0, #FFFFFF 2px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 2px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%), rgba(255,255,255,1);
  background-position: -2px -2px;
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-size: 34px 34px;
}

.piece {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```